# What is block provider?

Tags: blocks

I'm trying to create a custom block in Drupal 8 in one of my modules, and have followed the examples I've found in tutorials. But when I try to place the block, I'm getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: provider in
> Drupal\block\BlockPluginCollection->initializePlugin() (line 60 of
> /Users/pglatz/dev/wdocs/wdocs-d8-code/www/web/core/modules/block/src/BlockPluginCollection.php)

which is followed by this one:

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginException: Plugin (node_usage)
> instance class "Drupal\node_usage\Plugin\Block\NodeUsageBlock" does
> not exist. in
> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Factory\DefaultFactory::getPluginClass() (line
> 97 of
> /Users/pglatz/dev/wdocs/wdocs-d8-code/www/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Factory/DefaultFactory.php).

My class does exist; in `src/Plugin/Block/NodeUsageBlock.php` I have

```
namespace Drupal\node_usage\Plugin\Block;
```

and

```
class NodeUsaqeBlock extends BlockBase {
```

I don't know what the undefined index provider means or what's causing the error.

Comment: Show us the DocBlock section just ahead of the class declaration.
Also, I note that you spelled "NodeUsageBlock" with a "q" instead of a "g" in the class definition above. Is that typo in the original code?

Comment: what is the full module path ?

Comment: Thanks beltouche - simple misspelling. I appreciate having another set of eyes catching what I missed, and confirming that I'm not going crazy! best, Phil

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plugin not found](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/308296/plugin-not-found)